# an error after compiling the code-cannot find symbol

Tags: java

i have this code:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> output_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> pair_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (Iterator it=output_list.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            int pair_test = (int)output_list.next();
            for (int i=0; i<pair_list.length; i++)
            {

                if(!pair_list[i]==0)
                {
                    if (pair_list[i]==pair_test[i])
                    {
                        boolean check;
                        check=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but i got an error "cannot find symbol" while compiling.

```
symbol  : variable length
location: class java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>
                        for (int i=0; i<pair_list.length; i++)
                                                 ^
Prior.java:79: array required, but java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> found
                                if(!pair_list[i]==0)
                                             ^
Prior.java:79: incomparable types: boolean and int
                                if(!pair_list[i]==0)
                                                ^
Prior.java:81: array required, but java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> found
                                        if (pair_list[i]==pair_test[i])
                                                     ^
Prior.java:81: array required, but int found
                                        if (pair_list[i]==pair_test[i])
                                                                   ^
```

anyone can help me why i got this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pair_list.size()` instead of `pair_list.length`. The `pair_list` is a List not an array. I suggest looking at [the for-each loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) syntax also.
This `pair_list[i]` will not compile too. It is array syntax. Use `pair_list.get(i)` instead.

Comment: great!what about output_list.next()?

Comment: it's ok, but in fact for-each loop does exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

There's some work on this code

- as zacheusz already stated, a List is not an array, I think it's better to stay with the List but that means that means that .length becomes `.size()` and `[i]` becomes `.get(i)`
- you define `int pair_test = (int)output_list.next();` yet you say `pair_test[i]`, somethings is wrong there...
- `if(!pair_list[i]==0)` should become `if(!(pair_list[i]==0))`

Which gives us as a first iteration:

```
static List<Integer> output_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static List<Integer> pair_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer pair_test: output_list) {
    for (int i=0; i<pair_list.size(); i++) {
            if(!(pair_list.get(i)==0)) {
                // i suppose that this is what you mean 
                if (pair_list.get(i)==pair_test) { 
                    boolean check;
                    check=true;  
                    // this is pretty useless as it lives very locally and does 
                    // absolutely nothing anywhere else in the program....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, probably you can rewrite the inner loop like

```
for (Integer pair_list_element : pair_list) {
    if ((pair_list_element != 0) && (pair_list_element==pair_test)) {
        boolean check = true;
        // and then probably, because your condition was satisfied
        do_something_useful();
        // and get out
        break;
    }
}
```